# Sap custom table settings in Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Tags: oracle, abap

While creating table in sap I would like to check the feasibility of columnar table.
It is sap 7.50 but with oracle db.
Does Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 support columnar tables? From which version is it supported?

Comment: [In-memory column Store](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/in-memory.html).  [Oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/in-memory-column-store-12cr1) article

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database In-Memory (Database In-Memory) is a suite of features, first introduced in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), that greatly improves performance for real-time analytics and mixed workloads. The In-Memory Column Store (IM column store) is the key feature of Database In-Memory.

from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/inmem/intro-to-in-memory-column-store.html#GUID-BFA53515-7643-41E5-A296-654AB4A9F9E7)

Comment: so are u saying that we cannot create columnar tables in versions before Oracle 12c ?

Comment: And also is the data compression in 11g is same as column store ?